# Can't show the image in slider with yii2

Tags: image, yii2, show

I have code to show view like this

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php

            $items = [];

            foreach ($team->gallery as $item){
                $items[] = [
                        'content' => '<img style="width:300px;" src="'.$item->filepath.'"/>',
                        'caption' => '<h4>'.$item->name.'</h4><p>'.$item->description.'</p>',
                    ];
            }

            echo Carousel::widget([
                'items' => $items,
            ]);

            ?>
        </div>
```

and model for get galery like this

```
public function getLeague(){
        return $this->hasOne(Leagues::className(), ['id' => 'league_id']);
    }

    public function getGallery(){
        return $this->hasMany(TeamGalleries::className(), ['team_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

but i can't get the filepath in my databases therefore i can't show my picture in my website, how to solved this problem?

i use yii2 and the folder upload for my picture is in web folder in yii2 basic

Comment: Is `$item->filepath` e.g. 'myimage.png'? Or does it contain directories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are within the web folder you can easily use the [Yii aliases](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app), which have one entry for this folder: `@web`.

```
// Replace this

'<img style="width:300px;" src="'.$item->filepath.'"/>'

// with

'<img style="width:300px;" src="' . Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/' . $item->filepath . '"/>'
```

Further information about aliases in the [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases#resolving-aliases).